# How to create moment 1 map (also known as coordinate of maximum value of the spectral map)

Tags: python, astropy

How to create moment 1 map (also known as coordinate of maximum value of the spectral map) using python（astropy）?

Can `astropy` be used to plot moment 9? The data I got from using `.moment(order=9)` looks a bit strange, and I only saw three orders moment plots in the `astropy` documentation. Can `astropy` only plot up to the three orders?

Answer (score 0):

`moment`s are computed along the spectral axis with a given intensity and spectral coordinate. The spectral dimension is a quantity that characterizes spacetime geometry and topology like velocity, frequency, wavelength, or energy.

So for the `0`th `moment`, the integrated intensity over the spectral line is the (cube) unit times spectral axis unit (e.g. K km/s):

```
import astropy.units as u
from astropy.utils import data
from spectral_cube import SpectralCube
fn = data.get_pkg_data_filename('tests/data/example_cube.fits', 'spectral_cube')
cube = SpectralCube.read(fn)
print(cube)
moment_0 = cube.moment(order=0)
print(moment_0)
```

The `1`st `moment` is the intensity-weighted velocity of the spectral line, so the unit is the same as the spectral unit (e.g. km/s).

The `2`nd `moment` is the velocity dispersion or width of the spectral line so the unit is the spectral axis squared (e.g. km^2 / s^2).

By definition, there is no `9`th `moment`: https://spectral-cube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moments.html

Not that you can't have a `9`th `moment`, but it would be like km^9 / s^9.